# One git hook for multiple submodules

Tags: python, git, hook, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit

Is there a way how to use one git hook (for example the pre-commit) for all git submodules, to avoid duplicity?

When I use the pre-commit in the .git/hooks folder, it doesn't work for submodules. I have to copy the pre-commit file into every module in .git/modules/packages/name_of_package/hooks and then I have to maintain 10 separate scripts when doing changes.

Is there a ways how to include this hook in the repository, so everyone working on that project would automatically use it and wouldn't have to maintain the hook locally?

Comment: you could set `core.hooksPath` globally, but then that would change the hooks outside of your current repository

Comment: How about symlinks? If you are on Linux, that is.

Comment: I'm on a Windows, unfortunatelly.

Comment: Nothing to do with your question, but in English, "duplicity" doesn't mean "duplication", it means "deception". Same root word but the meaning has evolved. Unlike "enormity" (which evolved from "size" to "great evil" and is now evolving *back* to "size"), "duplicity" still just means double-dealing.

Comment: Wow, that's probably more useful information than an answer to my question. I use that word very often. :) Thanks.